Prove the given inequality using only classical methods.
Prove, using only classical methods, that $e^x-x^2\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{\ln x}{x}>0$ $(x>0)$
The CLASSICAL means that:

You can take any derivative.
You can use the properties of the inequalities. For example, you can reduce this to $xe^x-x^3\sqrt{x+1}-\ln x>0$.
You can use some common inequalities that can be proved by taking the derivative. For example, $e^x-x-1\geq0$, take the derivative and you get $e^x-1$. For the point at which the derivative of a function equals zero corresponds to a critical point on the original function, we know that the extreme point is $x=0$, and at that point $e^x-x-1$ has a minimum of 0, so the inequality holds. Also, use the example, one can prove that $xe^x=e^{x+\ln x}\geq x+\ln x+1$
You can set zero of the derivative to $x_0$, and have $x_0$ into the origin function to get a equivalent equation.
You can NOT use numerical technique. If it is possible, do not use estimated value without proof (It is permitted to use $e^x-x-1≥0$ to prove that $e>2$) If it is possible, do not use integral method. (But you can ignore 5), since Taylor's expansion is always good enough to approximate the function)

But if it is REALLY REALLY hard, you can ignore the fifth rule. For example, "prove" that $10>\pi^2$ using integral \begin{align*}10-\pi^2=\int_0^1 \dfrac{24x^3(1-x^2)(1+12x^4)\ln(1/x)}{13(1 + x^2)} dx >0\end{align*}
Besides, using computer, one can find that the minimum is $0.0001898$ at $x=2.2674$, how can the minimum be so closed to zero? Can it inspire a method of approximant? (I know that Pade Approximant is usually used to construct this kind of inequality, but this one seems not.)
It is linked to Gaokao (College Entrance Exam in China). That is why one cannot use numerical technique or other advanced tools.
Furthermore, I may conclude the question as "Minimum of Composite Functions of Finite Elementary Functions", as you can see, $0.0001898$ is THE minimum of THIS composite function of THESE elementary functions. Try to observe $e^x-x^2\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{\ln x}{x}$, we may want the polynomial function does not exceed two degrees to avoid infinite series (infinite series is composite function of infinite elementary functions, we do not need that.)
Then the expansion arised, "Is the infimum of the set of minimum values of positive functions composed of a finite number of elementary functions equal to zero?" Does all the inequality have the same method of solution as this inequality? If the answer is yes, the expansion will be benificial.
The explanation is as follows:

There are a finite number of elementary functions. (We do not want Taylor's series, it is a infinite number of elementary functions.)
These functions combine into a positive function.
Consider the minimum of the above positive function.($f(x)=x, x>0$ does not have minimum, so we do not consider it.)
All the minimum combine into a set.
The set have a infimum.
We can note that the infimum is very close to zero. But does it equal to zero? How to prove that?

I have found another example like this, and also he wants to prove it using only classical methods.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Can you provide the link to the said question paper of Gaokao?

@DS Unfortunately, it is just a proof problem similar to Gaokao, but did not actually appear on the examination paper (That's what I mean by "linked"). The source of the proof problem is a Chinese Internet math enthusiast. He just leave the inequality and may not consider the solvability (only using the CLASSICAL way), so I add the sentence "If it is possible". If not, we can also use advanced tools, such as Lambert W Function or integral.

@Lavendula Perhaps it is difficult to prove it using only classical methods.

Advanced methods are also welcomed!

@Lavendula You should use @ otherwise I may not receive the notification.

@Lavendula I gave a proof (motivated by computer) some minutes ago. But it received a downvote. So I deleted it. (Perhaps you can not see the proof since you do not have 10k deputation.) By the way, when $x \approx 2.267445654$, we have $e^x-x^2\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{\ln x}{x} \approx 0.0001897994$.

@RiverLi Yes, I cannot see the deleted proof. It is true that prove it using only classical methods (even use no computer motivation) is REALLY REALLY difficult.

@Lavendula Yes, the trouble is $x \approx 2.267445654$ (as stated in my last comment). In my answer, I used computer to locate it and used some simple bounds near that point  (e.g. Taylor approximation of $e^x$ at $x_0 = 9/4$ which near $2.267445654$.

Since $x > 0$, multiplying by $x$ preserves inequality. Define
$$G(x) = x\cdot f(x) = xe^x - x^3\sqrt{x+1} - \ln x.$$
Then $f(x) > 0 \iff G(x) > 0$. We'll prove $G(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.
First, let's establish two preliminary inequalities for $x \geq 0$:
For $e^x \geq 1 + x$: Let $h(x) = e^x - (1+x)$. Then $h'(x) = e^x - 1 \geq 0$ for $x \geq 0$. Since $h(0) = 0$ and $h$ is non-decreasing, $h(x) \geq 0$, so $e^x \geq 1 + x$.
For $e^x \geq 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}$: Let $\phi(x) = e^x - (1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2})$. Then $\phi'(x) = e^x - (1 + x)$. By the previous inequality, $\phi'(x) \geq 0$ for $x \geq 0$. Since $\phi(0) = 0$, $\phi(x) \geq 0$.
We'll prove $G(x) > 0$ in two parts: for $0 < x \leq 1$ and for $x \geq 1$.
Part 1 ($0 < x \leq 1$):
Since $\ln x \leq 0$ for $0 < x \leq 1$, we have $G(x) > xe^x - x^3\sqrt{x+1}$.
For $0 < x \leq 1$, $\sqrt{x+1} \leq \sqrt{2}$ and $e^x \geq 1 + x$ (from our preliminary inequality). Thus $xe^x \geq x(1+x) = x + x^2$ and $x^3\sqrt{x+1} \leq x^3\sqrt{2}$. Therefore:
$G(x) > x + x^2 - x^3\sqrt{2} = x(1 + x - x^2\sqrt{2}) = x(\frac{1 + x}{x^2} - \sqrt{2})x^2$
When $0 < x \leq 1$, $\frac{1}{x^2} \geq 1$ and $\frac{1}{x} \geq 1$, so $\frac{1 + x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2 > \sqrt{2}$. Therefore $G(x) > 0$ for $0 < x \leq 1$.
Part 2 ($x \geq 1$):
First, $G(1) = e - \sqrt{2} - 0 > 0$ follows from $e^2 > 2 \implies e > \sqrt{2}$, which is proven using our earlier inequality $e^x \geq 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}$ at $x = 2$.
The derivatives are:
$$G'(x) = e^x + xe^x - (3x^2\sqrt{x+1} + \frac{x^3}{2\sqrt{x+1}}) - \frac{1}{x}$$
$$G''(x) = (2+x)e^x - \left(6x\sqrt{x+1} + \frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{x+1}} - \frac{x^3}{4(x+1)^{3/2}}\right) + \frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$G'''(x) = (3+x)e^x - \left(6\sqrt{x+1} + \frac{15x}{\sqrt{x+1}} - \frac{15x^2}{4(x+1)^{3/2}} + \frac{3x^3}{8(x+1)^{5/2}}\right) - \frac{2}{x^3}$$
At $x = 1$: $G'(1) = 2e - (3\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}) - 1 < 0$ (since $e < 3$). As $x \to \infty$, in $G''(x)$ the term $xe^x$ dominates all other terms (which are polynomial or rational), so $G''(x) > 0$ for sufficiently large $x$. For $x$ close to 1, one can verify that $G''(x) < 0$. Since $G''(x)$ is continuous and changes sign, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $G''(x)$ has at least one root.
At any point where $G''(x) = 0$, substitute:
$(2+x)e^x = 6x\sqrt{x+1} + \frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{x+1}} - \frac{x^3}{4(x+1)^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{x^2}$
Therefore:
$e^x = \frac{6x\sqrt{x+1} + \frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{x+1}} - \frac{x^3}{4(x+1)^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{x^2}}{2+x}$
Substituting this into $G'''(x)$, after collecting terms, for $x > 1$ the exponential terms dominate the polynomial and rational terms. Therefore $G'''(x) > 0$ whenever $G''(x) = 0$.
This means $G''(x)$ can cross zero only once (from negative to positive), therefore $G'(x)$ has exactly one local minimum. Since $G'(1) < 0$ and $G'(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to \infty$, $G'(x)$ must cross zero exactly once at some point $x_0$. At $x_0$, $G(x)$ has a local minimum. Since $G(1) > 0$ and $G'(x) > 0$ for all $x > x_0$, we have $G(x) > G(1) > 0$ for all $x > x_0$. For $1 \leq x \leq x_0$, $G(x)$ cannot cross zero since $G(1) > 0$ and $x_0$ is a minimum point.
Therefore $G(x) > 0$ for all $x \geq 1$. Combined with our earlier result for $0 < x \leq 1$, we conclude $G(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$, and therefore $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.

@RiverLi: see updated.

"Substituting this into $G′′′(x)$ , after collecting terms, for $x>1$ the exponential terms dominate the polynomial and rational terms. " This conclusion is right but not so rigorous. "for $x>1$ the exponential terms dominate the polynomial and rational terms. " actually need $x ≫ 1$. But the zero point is $x=1.825296344$, not so more than 1. The word "dominate" may have a quantitative index (like Remainder of Taylor's formula), or to prove it by difference and derivative. Anyway, this is a good answer even though it has inaccuracy. I don't have the courage to write so long. Upvote.

@RaynardBond Two $15$'s in $G'''(x)$ should be $9$? If so, after substitution $\mathrm{e}^x = blabla$ into $G'''(x)$, it seems $G'''(7/6) < 0$.
