How to prove or disprove $4\ln(\frac{e^x-1}{x}) - \frac{2x}{e^x-1} \geq 3x-2$

There have $f(x)=4\ln(\frac{e^x-1}{x}) - \frac{2x}{e^x-1}$ (additional define $f(0)=-2$), then we can find it is seems that $g(x)= 3x -2$ is the tangent curve of $f(x)$ at $(0,-2)$, then we hypothesize below inequality is true:
$$4\ln(\frac{e^x-1}{x}) - \frac{2x}{e^x-1} \geq 3x-2$$
and the logarithmic form inequality:
$$4\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{\ln(x)}\right) - \frac{2\ln(x)}{x-1} \geq 3\ln(x)-2$$

But It seems that this is not so easy to the proof above inequality.
Attempt I
First try to prove that $f'(x) \geq 3$, but:
$f'(x) = \frac{2e^x(x^2-3x+4)+4e^{2x}(x-1)+2x-4}{x(e^x-1)^2}$, this is really not clear.
We now find $f'(x)$ can be further rewritten as:
$f'(x) = \frac{2[e^x(x-1)+1](2e^{x}+x-2)}{x(e^x-1)^2}$
Due to $e^{-x} \geq 1-x$ and $ \frac{2e^{x}+x-2}{x} \gt 1 $.
we can get $f'(x) \geq 0$, so f(x) is monotone increasing.
Then try to proof $f''(x) = \frac{-2e^x(x^3-6)-2e^{2x}(x^3+6)+4e^{3x}-4}{x^2(e^x-1)^3} \geq 0 $, it seems that this is true? but it still not clear.
I have checked the fuction graph by GeoGebra
It seems that GeoGebra gives a very strange graph near the ZERO like below:

This seems to imply $f''(x)$ is not strictly greater than zero!
But if I ask this $f''(x)$ in wolframalpha
wolframalpha shows that $f''(x) \gt 0$ is strictly true.
Which One is right?
If wolframalpha is right, this indicates that there is numerical problem in GeoGebra.
But if GeoGebra is right, then wolframalpha can not be trusted always.
Thanks so much for @Pranay 's elegant proof!
So This inequality is definnetly true.
And also shows that the GeoGebra has some kind of numerical problem.
Attempt II
Now I want to rigorously prove the monotonicity of $f(x)$ &    $f'(x)$ based on the monotonicity-definition.
Now we use a transformantion: $t = h(x) = \frac{e^x-1}{x}$.
Due to $e^x \geq 1+x$ is identically true, so $t \geq 0 $.
And $h'(x) = \frac{e^x(x-1)+1}{x^2} \geq 0 $  (Due to $e^{-x} \geq 1-x$ ).
So $t = h(x) = \frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is monotone increasing.
Then consider: $f(t)=4\ln(t) - \frac{2}{t}$, then we have $f'(t)=\frac{4t+2}{t^2} \geq 0 $ (Due to $t \geq 0 $), so $f(t)$ is strictly monotone increasing.
Consider any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ where $(x_1 < x_2)$,
Due to the monotonicity of $h(x)$, we will have:
$t_1 = h(x_1)$ < $t_2 = h(x_2)$
Due to monotonicity of $f(t)$, we have:
$f(t_1) = f(h(x_1)) = f(x_1)$ < $f(t_2) = f(h(x_2)) = f(x_2)$
So, for Any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ where $(x_1 < x_2)$, we have $f(x_1)$ < $f(x_2)$, Based on the monotonicity-definition, We can conclude that $f(x)$ is monotone increasing.
So we can get:
$f'(x) = \frac{2e^x(x^2-3x+4)+4e^{2x}(x-1)+2x-4}{x(e^x-1)^2}$ > $0$
Secondly, we consider to further prove $f'(x) \geq 3$, but till now, there is no idea.
Notes
I have checked $x=e^{-29}$ ,The above inequality is true, but for $x=e^{-30}$, it is wrong? It is possible a numerical error due to this kind of calculations reach the numerical precision limit in computer calculations?
Any idea?

Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Consider $(lhs-rhs)$ and look at the derivatives

@MartinR Thanks so much for your comment! I have no good idea about title, any good idea?

"proof" is a noun, "prove" is a verb.

I have a old question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4995648/prove-the-given-inequality-using-only-classical-methods. Maybe we can discuss together

The second derivative of $f(x)$ can be written as
$$
f''(x) = \frac{4}{x^2} - \frac{x \cosh \frac x2}{2\sinh^3 \frac x2},
$$
I want to show that $f''(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$. Since $f''(x)$ is an even function of $x$, it suffices to consider $x\ge 0$.

By substituting $x\to2u$, the inequality $f''(x) \ge 0$ becomes
$$
\frac{\sinh^3 u}{u^3} \ge \cosh u,
$$
for all $u\ge 0$. We can now use the same approach as in this beautiful answer to prove this inequality using AM-GM inequality. Define
$$g(u) = \frac{\sinh u}{\cosh^{1/3} u} - u.
$$
Its derivative is
$$
g'(u) = \frac{2\cosh^2 u + 1}{3 \cosh^{4/3}u} - 1 \ge 0,
$$
where I used
$$
2\cosh^2 u + 1 = \cosh^2 u + \cosh^2 u + 1 \ge 3 (\cosh^2 u \cdot \cosh^2 u \cdot 1)^{1/3} = 3 \cosh^{4/3}u.
$$
(The inequality is actually strict for $u>0$ because the AM-GM inequality is saturated if and only if $\cosh u = 1 \implies u = 0$.)

Since $g(0)=0$, it follows that $g(u) \ge 0$ for all $u\ge 0$, which means $f''(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0$. Hence, $f(x)$ is convex, and therefore, the graph of $f(x)$ lies above any of its tangents. In particular,
$$
f(x) \ge 3x-2,
$$
for all $x$.

This is really elegant proof. Thanks so much for your great work! This results indicates that GeoGebra indeed has some kind of numerial problem. And Also shows  that wolframalpha is much more powerfull
